# How to create and call Stored procedures on Snowflake from python?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have two simple queries

```
set recent_date = (select Max(FILE_DATE) from "PRODUCTS");

select P.*,V.ID as Var_ID,V.Name as Var_Name, V.external_id as Var_Ext_ID, V.color, V.original_price, V.Price
FROM "PRODUCTS" P
JOIN "VARIEY" V
    ON P.FILE_DATE = V.FILE_DATE
        AND P.ID = V.ID
WHERE P.FILE_DATE = $recent_date
```

I am calling the queries from Python(running them on snowflake is returning the result)
I am using the python snowflake connector and capturing the results in a Pandas dataframe.
I am trying to create a stored proc or any function so I can just call the proc/func instead of running the query again, I am new to snowflake and SP and unable to create one, Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

one option is you can create a view  something like as follows and select from the view. If you want to create a user defined function , you can see the link below.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions.html

```
CREATE VIEW VW_TST AS (
select P.*,V.ID as Var_ID,V.Name as Var_Name, V.external_id as Var_Ext_ID, V.color, V.original_price, V.Price
FROM "PRODUCTS" P
JOIN "VARIEY" V
    ON P.FILE_DATE = V.FILE_DATE
        AND P.ID = V.ID
WHERE P.FILE_DATE = (select Max(FILE_DATE) from "PRODUCTS")
)
```